# Strange behavior of tkz-fct and log(x) function

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-fct

I don't know whether the repo: https://github.com/tkz-sty/tkz-fct is active or not. So I raised an issue and asked a question here also.

OS: Win11 21H2
TexLive 2021
tkz-fct: 1.7c

Here is my minial working example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit[ymax=1.6, ymin=-1.6]
  % \tkzGrid
  \tkzDrawXY
  \tkzLabelX
  \tkzFct[domain= 0.01:10]{log(x)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

after compiling with `latexmk -pdf -shell-escape`, I got:

[image]

everything is right, I mean that the graph intersects axis x at (1, 0),
However after I added an `xstep`, things changed:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit[ymax=1.6, ymin=-1.6, xstep=3]
  % \tkzGrid
  \tkzDrawXY
  \tkzLabelX
  \tkzFct[domain= 0.01:10]{log(x)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The graph still intersects axis x at the first point (3, 0), not (1, 0).

Since I'm not familiar with Gnuplot, I can't debug if it is a tkz issue or a gnuplot issue.

Comment: About  the repo: https://github.com/tkz-sty/tkz-fct is  not active. I am not very comfortable with github. It was created by others and I don't have time to update because I don't understand all the way github works. If you still have problems, send me an email directly. My email is in the documentation.

Comment: The answer to the question should be posted as an answer and not in the question. Surprisingly, users look for answers in the answers, not in the question ;-)

Comment: @VincentFourmond You are right, I'll move it into a new answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For function expressions you should use log(\x) , not log(x)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit[ymax=1.6, ymin=-1.6, xstep=3]
  % \tkzGrid
  \tkzDrawXY
  \tkzLabelX
  \tkzFct[domain= 0.01:10]{log(\x)} % log(x) ---> log(\x)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why `x` still works? What is the difference between `x` and `\x`?

Comment: @projetmbc I added a piece of  document in my question, have a look.

Comment: Thanks for this !

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved, in the [document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-fct/doc/tkz-fct.pdf) of `tkz-fct`, at the description in `\tkzFct`, there is a sentence in french:

> La fonction est donnée en utilisant la syntaxe de gnuplot. x est la variable sauf si `xstep` est différent de 1, dans ce cas la variable est `\x`.

After translating it into English:

> The function is given using the syntax of gnuplot. x is the variable unless `xstep` is different from 1, in which case the variable is `\x`.

Therefore I have to use `log(\x)` instead `log(x)`, as @ljguo mentioned.

Comment: Evidence from `tkz-fct.sty` ([code](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-fct/tkz-fct.sty?view=markup&pathrev=61949#l116)) for why `\x` is forcibly required when `xstep` is different from 1: it locally assigns `\def\x{(x*\tkz@init@xstep)}`.